# Using formatting java extension in Play2 framework

Tags: playframework-2.2, date-formatting

What's the equivalent of this expression in Play2:

```
${new Date(new Date().getTime() - 1000000).since()}
```

If there is none, can you recommend something else? I've found moment.js, but not sure if I can incorporate that in scala template

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are talking about using these expressions in the Twirl templates.

Since Scala interoperates seemlessly with Java, there is no need to implement classes like `Date` in the Scala class library – you can simply import the classes of the corresponding Java packages.

```
@import java.util.Date

@{new Date(new Date().getTime() - 1000000)}
```

There is no `since()` method defined on `java.util.Date` so that means you cannot use it. You are of course free to use other libraries - like JodaTime - or use the [new Java 8 Time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) to achive the desired functionality and for some other date/time manipulations.

---

`moment.js` is a nice library I am using myself. You can rely on it but then you have to keep in mind that this is a JavaScript-based library and this means using it on the client side (at least in connection with Play Framework).